# Conversion from const int to int giving strange results.Can anyone explain the reason for the strange results

Tags: c++, c

When I tried below code I got strange results.I am trying to change value of constant by using the pointers.But when I output the results pointer value and the original variable variable value its giving two different values.Can anyone explain what exactly happens when explicit conversion take place?

```
int main()
{
    int *p ;
    const int a = 20;
    p=(int *)&a;
    *p = *p +10;
    cout<<"p is"<<*p<<"\na is"<<a;
}
```

output:
p is 30
a is 20

Comment: "I am trying to change value of constant" ....why!? :P

Comment: possible duplicate of [behavior of const\_cast in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602859/behavior-of-const-cast-in-c)

Comment: @mtijanic Why not? This guy is trying to learn something.

Comment: As in all those dupes: You cannot change constant data because it is constant.

Comment: section 7.1.6.1 of the C++ draft ( http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) : "any attempt to modify a const object during its lifetime (3.8) results in undefined behavior"

Comment: Actually you cannot change constant data because it's 'probably const folded' by your compiler. In other words, it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of - You really shouldn't be doing this. `const` is a constant, meaning *don't change it*! :)

Now to explain what happens (I think):

The space on the stack is allocated for both variables, `p` and `a`. This is done for `a` because it has been referenced by an address. If you removed `p`, you'd effectively remove `a` as well.

The number `20` is indeed written to the `a` variable, and modified to `30` via `p`, which is what is being printed.

The `20` printed is calculated at compile time. Since it is a `const`, the compiler optimized it away and replaced with `20`, as if you did a `#define a 20`.

Answer (score 5):

Both C and C++ say that any attempt to modify an object declared with the `const` qualifier results in undefined behavior.

So as `a` is object is const qualified, the `*p = *p +10;` statement invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: The key point here being that hiding a `const` object behind a pointer to a non-`const` type does not make it any less `const`, nor somehow define any modification behavior for it.  This is the basic reason for buying into `const`-correctness if you are going to use any `const` data at all.

Answer (score 2):

Don't Do That.

If you would write this code in C++ with an explicit cast, you would get something like this:

```
int main()
{
    int *p ;
    const int a = 20;
    p= const_cast<int*>(&a); // the change
    *p = *p +10;
    cout<<"p is"<<*p<<"\na is"<<a;
}
```

Now, this code tells a bit more about what's going on: the constant is cast to a non-constant.

If you are writing a compiler, constants are special variables that are allowed to be 'folded' in the const folding phase. Basically this means that the compiler is allowed to change your code into this:

```
int main()
{
    int *p ;
    const int a = 20;
    p= const_cast<int*>(&a);
    *p = *p +10;
    cout<<"p is"<<*p<<"\na is" << 20; // const fold
}
```

Because you're also using `&a`, you tell the compiler to put the value `20` in a memory location. Combined with the above, you get the exact results you describe.

Answer (score 0):

This is undefined behavior.

A compiler can assume that nothing is going to change the value of a const object. The compiler knows that the value of "a" is 20. You told the compiler that. So, the compiler actually goes ahead and simply compiles the equivalent of

```
cout << "p is" << *p << "\na is" << 20;
```

Your compiler should've also given you a big fat warning, about "casting away const-ness", or something along the same lines, when it tried to compile your code.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is defined as undefined behaviour (as everyone else tells you), it could be that your compiler has allocated a storage location (int) for the const int; that is why the `*p= *p + 10` works, but may have repaced `a` in the output statement with the value 20, as it is supposed to be constant.