# How to read integer value into constant in C++?

Tags: java, c++

How to properly re-write this code from Java to C++:

```
final int number = scanner.nextInt();
```

I’m trying `const number << cin;` but it doesn’t work.

The number should be constant.

Is it possible in C++?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006161/changing-the-value-of-const-variable-in-c
Please check here, I think this question is duplicate.

Comment: IILE? `auto const number = [](){int x; cin >> x; return x;}();`?

Answer (score 7):

You cannot assign to a `const`. You must initialize it:

```
int x = 0;
std::cin >> x;
const int number = x;
```

If you like, put it inside a function, so you can write:

```
const int number = read_number();
```

As mentioned in comments, with a immediately invoked lambda expression you can do that all in one line:

```
const int number = [](){ int x; std::cin >> x; return x; }();
```

The lambda expression is `[](){ int x; std::cin >> x; return x; }` and `()` immediately calls it and `number` is initialized with the returned value.

Comment: or `int const number = *istream_iterator<int>{cin};`

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili thats neat. Maybe a bit too fancy. Is it always safe to dereference the iterator?

Comment: And then you can make that function a lambda. And call it immediately :)

Comment: @spectras I saw the comment above, but stealing someone else idea is always a bit lame. I will add it anyhow

Comment: I am not planning to write an answer, and the idea is nothing new. Feel free to add it :)

Comment: @spectras anyhow I am expecting that someone will find a duplicate for this question. (the one that has been proposed isnt one imho)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 just like all iterators, you have to compare it with end-iterator before dereferencing like here https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8ch3KW

Answer (score 1):

There is something called [`istream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator). This class lets you to iterate over a stream as if it were a container. Here is how you use it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    std::istream_iterator<int> it{ std::cin }, end{};

    // Must test against end
    const int n1 = it == end ? 0 : *it++;
    const int n2 = it == end ? 0 : *it++;
}
```

This assigns a default `0` if the stream fails. You could do the error handling other ways too. This is particularly useful for making the variable `const`, and the iterator can be used as many times as you like. You can use it to initialize containers like `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<int> vec{ it, end };
```

This will read all integers until the stream fails, end of file, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with constructing a temporary "istream_iterator".
Example:

```
const int number = *istream_iterator<int>(cin);
```

Comment: is it always safe to dereference the iterator?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 not if cin was closed.

Comment: @spectras Is the behavior undefined then or are you guaranteed an exception? If the behavior is undefined, is there something like an `.at(0)` member function that guarantees an exception?

Comment: @EOF From cppreference: *“When a valid std::istream_iterator reaches the end of the underlying stream, it becomes equal to the end-of-stream iterator. Dereferencing or incrementing it further invokes undefined behavior.”*

Answer (score -4):

Try this instead:

```
//Declare int variable
int number;

//Read variable
cin >> number;
```

Comment: What did you change, and why does that fix it? The answer should explain.